# Branching strategy to avoid conflicts on two branches

Tags: git

In my team, we have three developers working on the same repository.
The idea is to make sure to pull it from the `main` branch before pushing new changes to the branch and then followed by a pull request.
My question: Is the order of the following commands correct or efficient way?

**Commands**

```
git checkout branchName
git add .    
git commit -m "Fix Code"    
git checkout main     
git pull --rebase   
git checkout branchName  
git rebase main    
git push -f origin branchName
```

Comment: Always pull first before adding any changes.

Comment: Do not do `rebase main` if developers work independently. rebase will override main branch history. Do simple `merge`.

Comment: @ujjawal-bhandari, I've provided an answer below. Please let me know if it worked. I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the entire flow of how to do it.

First, before starting the work, make sure you're starting from an up to date `main` branch like this:

```
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout branchName
```

Then do the changes on your branch called `branchName`, and make a commit there:

```
// Do your code changes
git add .    
git commit -m "Fix Code"
```

Let's say, meanwhile someone updated the `main` branch.
So, you'll need to rebase your code before pushing.
Do the following:

```
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout branchName
git rebase main
```

Now you have up-to-date code on your branch as well.
Feel free to push:

```
git push origin branchName
```

Now you can create a pull request and merge it to the `main` as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I used to do what was proposed in [Just Shadow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70154260/184546), and that works fine. It's also what most Git tutorials recommend when you're starting out with Git. But since you specifically asked for an "efficient way", here's what I currently do which I've found to be significantly more "efficient":

- Rarely, if ever, checkout `main`! This may sound crazy at first, but there are multiple reasons for this: It very quickly becomes out of date, you might forget to update it and accidentally use an older version of it, and you actually don't ever need to check it out.
- Anytime you would have previously used your local copy of `main`, use `origin/main` instead (assuming you are calling your remote "origin", which is the default).

If you do this, the workflow is simplified. The biggest change you need to make conceptually is that you will now rarely, if ever use the `pull` command. Instead you'll use `fetch` to update your copy of the remote branches, which you reference with `origin`. For example:

**Create a new branch:**

```
git fetch
git switch -c branchname origin/main --no-track
```

**Later when you wish to update your branch with the latest main:**

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/main
```

It takes some getting used to, but once you become comfortable with this it's second nature. The key to understanding it is that there are 3 conceptual "buckets" to think about in Git:

1. Your local branches.
2. Your copy of the remote branches.
3. The actual remote branches.

Every time you `git fetch`, you're basically copying #3 to #2. (BTW, pull does a fetch behind the scenes.) The trick is realizing that you can access anything in bucket #2 without needing to check it out, if you don't wish to.

**Side Note:** the title of your question:

> Branching strategy to avoid conflicts on two branches

suggests that the branching strategy you use can help avoid conflicts, but that isn't necessarily true. Even keeping your not-yet-merged branches up to date with the latest `main` (or `origin/main`) can still lead to conflicts, but if you do it often the conflicts will be relatively small and easier to resolve, compared with long running feature branches that don't get updated until just before a PR is created and could potentially have larger conflicts to deal with.