# Do we have to merge branches separately in VS Code and in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, branch, branching-and-merging

I am working on my first major project.

1. I made a new branch (left-nav) using GitHub and worked on it in VS Code.
2. As my work is completed in that particular branch (left-nav) I merged it to the master branch using GitHub.
3. But after merging branch(left-nav) with the master branch in GitHub, when I opened VS Code with the master branch as an active branch, the code of branch (left-nav) was not merged in VS Code whereas when I see the same file in GitHub it has all the code in it.

Do I have to merge code separately in GitHub as well as in VS Code, or I am getting it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Did you _pull_ your changes from GitHub after merging it? Nothing to do with VS Code _per se_ but you probably need to sync your local repo with the remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pull the new changes from GitHub using `git pull origin master`

Note:

I would advise you to merge the branches locally & then pushing your changes to GitHub. This will be helpful in case something breaks.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to merge code separately in GitHub as well as in VS Code, or I am getting it wrong somewhere?

**No, you don't need to merge separately; you are just missing a step.**

Basically your local copy of the repo is out of date. If you perform a `git fetch` to update your copy of what's on GitHub, and then take a look at `origin/master` you will see your changes there (this assumes your remote is called "origin", which is the default).

If you also want to see those changes on your local copy of `master`, you need to update that copy of `master` with what's in `origin`, and one way to do that is to checkout `master` and `merge` the latest commits from `origin/master` into it. (Note the command `pull` will do a `fetch` and `merge` in a single command.)

This is slightly more advanced, but once you get the hang of dealing with `origin`, you don't really need to keep a local copy of `master` anymore since you can already view what you wish to see using `origin/master` instead. Coincidentally, I just [answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70159063/184546) today which explains this concept in more detail, which is definitely relevant to your specific question too.